# How to make Zalenium work with AWS Fargate?

Tags: selenium, docker, devops, aws-fargate, zalenium

### The issue

I would like to use Zalenium in a container using AWS Fargate. However, to do so, we have to pull two images: Zalenium and Selenium. Indeed, during its process, Zalenium creates containers using Selenium image. Therefore it needs to find the Image somewhere.

### A possible solution

I was thinking of creating  an ubuntu container with Docker installed which would run the following commands:

It would first pull the images

```
docker pull elgalu/selenium
docker pull dosel/zalenium
```

and then create a Zalenium container with the Docker socket mounted to create another container:

```
docker run --rm -ti --name zalenium -p 4444:4444 \
      -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
      -v /tmp/videos:/home/seluser/videos \
      --privileged dosel/zalenium start
```

That would mean I would create a container that would inside another container that would be inside another container which doesn't sound straightforward.

So before doing that, I wanted to check if someone wouldn't have a better solution. As being new to AWS, I might have missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull the image implicity through the Zalenium container, just check https://opensource.zalando.com/zalenium/#tryit, section "Or without pulling elgalu/selenium explicitly:"

Example:

```
    # Pull Zalenium
    docker pull dosel/zalenium

    # Run it!
    docker run --rm -ti --name zalenium -p 4444:4444 \
      -e PULL_SELENIUM_IMAGE=true \
      -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
      -v /tmp/videos:/home/seluser/videos \
      --privileged dosel/zalenium start

    # Point your tests to http://localhost:4444/wd/hub and run them

    # Stop
    docker stop zalenium
```